# Null condition in qliksense expression

Tags: null, expression, qliksense

i have this expression

```
sum( {<code={'12','13,'16','90'}, type={'abc','def','xyz'}, type2={'general'}>} net_pre)
-
sum( {<code={'12','13,'16','90'}, type={'abc','def','xyz'}, type2={'general'}>} tax_prem)
```

in that i want to add condition

```
A.Code Is Null Or (A.Code Is Not Null And A.MClass Is Null)
```

Currenly i did not not tried anything about that and dont know how to add this condition in expression

how i modify expression

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

to get null records we need to select all and subtract not nulls for example (set $ and exclude $ set with all A.code with values:

```
sum( {$-$<A.code={"*"}>} net_pre)
```

then you need to keep adding conditions (+ for or as we want both sets, * for or - set intersection)

```
sum( {
     ($-$<A.code={"*"}>) 
     +
     ($<A.code={"*"}> * ($-$<A.MClass={"*"}>))
     } net_pre)
```

I haven't validate it. If you want me to do it you need to share your qvf file.